# How to perform an itemless search for a ComboBox after reloading it?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am using a ComboBox that when loading it the first time I can get the items in the combo list but when I reload this combo I can not get the items in the combo list anymore. What is the best way to reload this combo to keep searching the ComboBox list?

```
ComboBox2.DataSource = Nothing

ComboBox2.Items.Clear ()


If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex> 0 Then
Load (ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
End if
```

Comment: Is the combobox originally loaded from a DataSource?

Comment: Yes in calling this function named load I load as follows Combobox.Datasource = New BindingSource (dictionary) This dictionary being a return from my CRUD. I go through this routine every time the user changes the filter type, but the second time even though I use the same filter I can no longer type to find the item in the ComboBox

Answer (score 1):

To clear the items that are in the drop down menu

`combobox.SelectedIndex = -1`

will work. To clear what the user types in the combobox

`combobox.Text = String.Empty`

will work because the combobox also has a text property. Use both of these to ensure it will clear the fields.

Answer (score 0):

I got a palliative solution that solved my problem, I realized that when setting the DataSource property = nothing was changed two properties BindingFieldEmpty = true and DisplayMember = "" this only occurred after assigning the first DataSource now I create a new list instance and step the properties of this new BindingSource list (dictionary, nothing) to zero the DataSource